# how to print mathematical equations in swift

Tags: swift, math, println

Something such as:

```
sqrt(1+2+3)

println("√(1+2+3)") // NOT WORK DEFINITLY
```

Is there any way to print this equation out using the standard library?
Thanks

Comment: `println("√(1+2+3)")` really prints out the mathematical equation. Do you mean the **result** of the expression?

Comment: I didn't mean the result. I know it pints out "√(1+2+3)", but can I make it look more like the real equation in our math textbook? In this case, I mean the upper bar of the square root symbol should be long enough to include "1+2+3"

Comment: That needs a graphical renderer. You can't print that in plain text mode.